# Knapsack (what?) in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, genetic-algorithm

I'm sorry for the title; frankly speaking, I don't even know whether my question is related to the Knapsack problem.  Was reading some stuff about genetic algorithms and found this "Knapsack Problem".

I need someone to kick me in the right direction:

I am developing a python web application for a factory.  So in a factory, they have something called an order.  An order contains one or many products.  There's a concept of mismatch, which is actually a negative number used to indicate how much less (in terms of quantity) a particular product will appear in an order.

Think of a matrix with the columns being products and the rows being orders.  Just assume that all orders(rows) contain all products(columns).  Again, there are 8 orders Orders 1 to Orders 8 and 5 products, Product 1 to Product 5.

Supposing, now I have a mismatch of 6 for Product 1.  I need to split the number six equally amongst all 8 of the orders, **randomly**.  So obviously 2 orders won't have mismatch quantities.  Then I have a mismatch of 9 for Product 2.  I split the mismatch quantity over 8 Orders as evenly as possible, **randomly**.  This goes on for each Product.  Now here comes the kicker, while I am in the process of splitting the mismatches randomly across all Orders, I need to ensure that the total mismatches per order (meaning for that row) are kept at a minimal.  This means the total mismatches across an order needs to be the lowest possible number.

```
    |-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
    |  P1 |  P2 |  P3 |  P4 |  P5 |
    -------------------------------
O1  |  2  |  1  |  1  |  0  |  2  |  6
    -------------------------------
O2  |  1  |  2  |  1  |  1  |  1  |  6
    -------------------------------
O3  |  2  |  2  |  1  |  0  |  1  |  6
    -------------------------------
O4  |  1  |  2  |  0  |  1  |  1  |  5
    -------------------------------
       6     7     3     2     5
```

Do you get it?  I need to code this in Python, and I have no idea where to start.

Comment: I don't get it. If you have a matrix of zeros and you are adding a given number of ones to each column, then the total number of ones within the matrix is simply the sum of all columns. You cannot keep the number to minimal. (or write some example code with input and possible output)

Comment: The problem is that I don't know where to begin to write any code for this.

Well, each column may have a different number, 9, 5, 13.  However when dividing the number across the rows as equally as possible in a random fashion, I also need to consider whether the summation of that row (not column) is kept to a minimal.  If the summation of one row is 13, and the rest of the rows were 3 or something, that means that the initial division of the mismatch across the rows were not *equally* split.

Comment: A matrix can be written as a pseudotable using monospaced font. Just indent these lines by four spaces and it will look like code. Have a look at other questions/answers.

Comment: Given that you can put positive or negative numbers in each cell, is there a maximum absolute value for each cell? It seems that if an order called for 10 items of product 'j', it wouldn't make sense to put a number less than -10 in the corresponding cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the OP's problem has two requirements: **randomly** and **evenly**. It's a bit conflicting though, so I guess "truly random" is impossible.

Here is my try

Using OP's example, we have 4 orders and 5 products. Starting from the first product, we split the numbers randomly, so each product will at least have floor(6/4)=1 mismatches. Then we randomly put the remaining 2 mismatches to 2 products.

```
    |-----|
    |  P1 |
    -------
O1  |  2  | 2
    -------
O2  |  1  | 1
    -------
O3  |  2  | 2
    -------
O4  |  1  | 1
    -------
       6
```

Next, we take care of the second product. Similarly, we split the numbers randomly first, so each product will at least have floor(7/4)=1 mismatches. Now for the remaining 3 mismatches, to make it as **even** as possible, we first assign them to O2 and O4, since last time they have 1 less mismatch than others. For the remaining 1 mismatches, we again randomly assign it to one of the product.

```
    |-----|-----|
    |  P1 |  P2 |
    -------------
O1  |  2  |  1  | 3
    -------------
O2  |  1  |  2  | 3
    -------------
O3  |  2  |  2  | 4
    -------------
O4  |  1  |  2  | 3
    -------------
       6     7
```

Repeat this process for all the products.

Using this way, you can guarantee that it's as **even** as possible (the biggest difference is 1), also you get some degree of **random**

Comment: Wow that was spot on.  I'm surprised you even understand what I was trying to say.

Ok now, what happens when some orders don't have some products in them.  For instance, what if O3 didn't contain P2?  I'll try to figure the rest of this on my own, but thank you so much.  Do you know what this kind of problem is called so that I can google more about this?

Comment: @Mark Glad to help :) however I'm afraid I have no idea if there is a name for this kind of problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You almost have an integer linear programming problem, except that the objective function (the maximum of the row sums) you want to minimize is not linear. Look at `scipy` for solving optimization problems.

This thread, https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/83/is-there-a-high-quality-nonlinear-programming-solver-for-python, may also help.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you do it this way:

You have a sequence of items to put into the orders, the sequence consisting of items of the first product, followed by items of the second product, etc.

You put the first item into the first order, the second item into the second order, etc, wrapping around at some point to the first order again, round and round, until you have no more items.

Would that work?